# Installing the bootloader

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, bootloader

I have a new Lenovo idea pad (U410) with Windows 8 pre-installed. I've partitioned the hard drive and I'm able to install Ubuntu without errors. I've done this a couple times, but I'm not sure where to place the boot loader. I have an SSD + standard HD (1TB) on my computer. I believe Windows 8's loader is on the 1 TB drive.

I've tried putting the Ubuntu loader on both drives and while it says there wasn't any errors, I'm unable to load directly into it.

I've tried using EasyBCD but every thing I try there says that it was unable to load Windows.

Right now, in order to get into Ubuntu, in Windows I have to go to Settings > Power > Shift + Restart > Troubleshoot > Advanced options > UEFI Firmware Settings > Restart. Then when it restarts I am able to check a separate drive (the SSD) and that loads GRUB. Then I can choose Ubuntu. If I try choosing Windows from Grub it errors out and I have to restart the computer. This is why I do not want to change the BIOS to load from the SSD first.

So how do I properly clean this mess up and allow me to duel boot? I don't care if I do that through GRUB or through the Windows loader.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not really a need for EasyBCD with UEFI as every system you install will install a boot loader into a folder in your efi partition.

But if you have booting in BIOS mode from SSD, you may have installed in BIOS/legacy/CSM mode not UEFI. Boot-Repair can usually convert a BIOS install to UEFI by uninstalling grub-pc and installing grub-efi.

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot.:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

You can repair many boot issues with this or 'Create BootInfo' report (Other Options) & post the link it creates, so we can see your exact configuration and diagnose advanced problems.

You may want to go back thru the instructions on UEFI installs. If you have the smaller SSD, it probably is an Ultrabook and you may also have RAID issues & video issues. If you can set video mode to boot from use nVidia and add nomodeset to grub's linux line, use e to edit on grub menu.

Also shows Windows 8 screens

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system-uefi-supported)

Shows install with screen shots.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions